# 'Error loading shared libraries: libgmp.so.10' while deploying Haskell web server to AWS Beanstalk using Docker

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, haskell, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

My Dockerrun.aws.json looks like this:

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1",
  "Image": {
    "Name": "abcd/haskell-binary-image",
    "Update": "true"
  },
  "Ports": [
    {
      "ContainerPort": "6000"
    }
  ]
}
```

When I run `eb local run --port 6000` on EB CLI, I get the following error:

```
latest: Pulling from abcd/haskell-binary-image
Digest: sha256:230d38fb8b3a8e95d538e5317982d6b85d12de5f02c3b07de369319766d657fc
Status: Image is up to date for abcd/haskell-binary-image:latest
docker.io/abcd/haskell-binary-image:latest
Sending build context to Docker daemon  4.608kB
Step 1/2 : FROM abcd/haskell-binary-image
 ---> b8d59f6eff42
Step 2/2 : EXPOSE 6000
 ---> Using cache
 ---> fcb117fc41f8
Successfully built fcb117fc41f8
/bin/image-exe: error while loading shared libraries: libgmp.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I run into the same issue when I run it on EB using the web client. The server runs using the same docker image on my local machine, just not on Elastic Beanstalk. My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM fpco/stack-build:lts-15.16
ADD src src
ADD app app
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
  ca-certificates \
  libgmp-dev
ADD .stack-work/install/x86_64-linux-dkda49f7ca9b244180d3cfb1987cbc9743/219c4eef637de81431e864021af4dfc5a76fc6002e563868e1dfc24dcc774697/8.8.3/bin /bin/
EXPOSE 5000
ENTRYPOINT [ "/bin/image-exe" ]
```

EDIT:
Running `obj dump -p image-exe | grep NEEDED` on the binary lists the following as shared library dependencies:

```
  NEEDED               libm.so.6
  NEEDED               libpthread.so.0
  NEEDED               librt.so.1
  NEEDED               libutil.so.1
  NEEDED               libdl.so.2
  NEEDED               libz.so.1
  NEEDED               libgmp.so.10
  NEEDED               libc.so.6
```

Comment: Is it, perhaps, not on `PATH`?

Comment: Can you provide minimal working example of your Dockerfile? I could run it on my EB environment to test, but I can't do this because I don't know what `ADD .stack-work/install/ ...` is.

Comment: .stack-work/install/.... links to an executable binary from my Haskell program that I am adding in this container. Not sure how to provide an example here that you could test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `ldd` on the `/bin/image-exe`, this will provide you with dynamically linked libraries missing from your image, and you need to add them to you `Dockerfile`, I do see however, you've already added `libgmp-dev`, but you might be missing other dependencies.

Comment: Updated the question with a list of shared libraries from the binary. Also, I am able to run the docker image on my local computer using `docker run --publish 8000:5000 --detach --name cont_name haskell-binary-image`

Comment: I think google search would do the trick now, search for each package and see what needs  to be installed for each one

Comment: `libgmp.so.10` (one that returned an error) is found in `libgmp-dev` package. I am now thinking the path where it is trying to find the shared libraries are incorrect.

Comment: Hey, `ldd` command supplies the path as well and the lib name

Comment: Are you using linux?

Comment: I am using Mac OS, I found `objdump -p image-exe | grep NEEDED` is a substitute for `ldd` but only returns the libraries required.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216976/discussion-between-frozenone-and-fifthcode).

Comment: A lot of them install libgmp10, so you could try with that as well